# Roblox: Check for Tool in Inventory

Tags: roblox

How can I make a script that checks for a specific tool in the players inventory on execute?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should try yourself first and then post the code. Then we can tell you what went wrong so you can learn from your mistakes. It would also help you understand the code at a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

The best way if you know the name of the tool would be to try and `FindFirstChild` and then check the result in an if statement.

The code to do something like this is quite simple as seen below:

```
local player = game.Players.MaxLi
--You can change how you get to the player as you need

if player.Backpack:FindFirstChild("Tool name goes here") then
    print("Tool exists")
    --Put the code you want to run if they have the tool here
end
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! A quick question - how would i find the player?

Comment: If you are using an onTouched function it would be `onTouched(hit), hit.Parent.Player` where hit is the part that touched the brick/part. If you know the players name then just do `player = game.Players.FindFirstChild(nameHere)`

Comment: @Max Li Just a little suggestion, you can also do something like

pcall(function()
if player.Character:FindFirstChild("Tool name goes here") then
local tool = player.Character:FindFirstChild("Tool name goes here");
if tool:IsA("Tool")then
print("Tool exists");
end;
end;
end);

This would detect if the tool is equipped by the character, if you mix this plus your code, you'd have a "full check", just to make sure the player has that tool.